# Select query for returning different data based on creation time

Tags: postgresql, subquery, aggregate, pivot

I have a view, which will select data from table `reports`. The select will filter the data based on multiple dates.

`reports table`: `id, key_id, position, created_at`

My select:

```
pr.key_id,
COALESCE(CASE WHEN date(pr.created_at) = date(current_date - interval '1' day) THEN array_agg(DISTINCT pr.position) ELSE '{0}' END ) AS yesterday,
COALESCE(CASE WHEN date(pr.created_at) = date(current_date - interval '2' day) THEN array_agg(DISTINCT pr.position) ELSE '{0}' END ) AS last_week,
COALESCE(CASE WHEN date(pr.created_at) = date(current_date - interval '3' month) THEN array_agg(DISTINCT pr.position) ELSE '{0}' END ) AS last_month,
```

Even if I group by key_id and date the result is not grouped.

Example of result I get now:

1. key_id: 1 yesterday: {1} last_week: {0} last_month: {0} created_at: '2014-04-11'
2. key_id: 1 yesterday: {0} last_week: {1} last_month: {0} created_at: '2014-04-10'
3. key_id: 1 yesterday: {0} last_week: {0} last_month: {1} created_at: '2014-04-09'

What I expect:

1. key_id: 1 yesterday: {1} last_week: {1} last_month: {1} created_at: '2014-04-11'

With this query I get what I want. Is there a better way of doing it?

```
SELECT
    k.name,
    array_agg(DISTINCT position),
    (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT position) FROM project_reports prk WHERE prk.project_id = pr.project_id AND prk.keyword_id = pr.keyword_id AND date(prk.created_at) = date(current_date - interval '1' day)) as y_position,
    (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT position) FROM project_reports prk WHERE prk.project_id = pr.project_id AND prk.keyword_id = pr.keyword_id AND date(prk.created_at) = date(current_date - interval '7' day)) as last_week,
    (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT position) FROM project_reports prk WHERE prk.project_id = pr.project_id AND prk.keyword_id = pr.keyword_id AND date(prk.created_at) = date(current_date - interval '1' month)) as last_month,
    (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT position) FROM project_reports prk WHERE prk.project_id = pr.project_id AND prk.keyword_id = pr.keyword_id AND date(prk.created_at) = date(current_date - interval '3' month)) as three_month,
    (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT position) FROM project_reports prk WHERE prk.project_id = pr.project_id AND prk.keyword_id = pr.keyword_id AND date(prk.created_at) = date(current_date - interval '6' month)) as six_month,
    (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT position) FROM project_reports prk WHERE prk.project_id = pr.project_id AND prk.keyword_id = pr.keyword_id AND date(prk.created_at) = date(current_date - interval '12' month)) as last_year,
    date(pr.created_at)
FROM project_keywords pk
INNER JOIN keywords k ON pk.keyword_id = k.id
INNER JOIN project_reports pr USING (project_id, keyword_id)
GROUP BY k.name, date(pr.created_at), pr.project_id, pr.keyword_id
```

Comment: So what `COALESCE` is supposed to do there?  Anyway, what you included is not a query, just a piece of it.  Also, without example data it is hard to get what you are asking about.  Still, I guess you want to do something like `SELECT (SELECT {yesterday}), (SELECT {last_week}), (SELECT {last_month})`

Comment: Add the full query you used, not a crippled version.

Comment: @dezso Sorry, for not printing all the query, also with your answer I got what I wanted, is there any other way to get the same data without so many selects?

Comment: @alex It seems you are trying to squeeze 2 reports into one, with this query.

Comment: @dezso: Oh thnx. I just read *"any built-in or user-defined aggregate function can be used as a window function"* in the docs.

Comment: Why are you joining to `project_keywords`? It's only possible purpose is to demand an existing row there. Is that the intention? Since `keyword_id` is in the table `project_reports` (redundantly?), we don't need `project_keywords` for this query. Table definitions would help to clarify. What you get in psql with `\d tbl`.

Comment: @ypercube: I don't think windows function would get us far here, since the correlated subqueries return constant values per `(keyword_id, project_id)`. I *think* I squeezed the maximum out of this one by joining to a single, cross-tabulated subquery ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I guessed the missing pieces correctly, this query using a `crosstab()` function should do the job (and *much* faster than the original - except for small cardinalities where not much can be gained to begin with):

It requires that you install the additional module `tablefunc` first (once per database. Detailed instructions in this related answer on SO:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

```
SELECT name, project_id, positions, created_day
      ,yesterday, last_week, last_month, three_month, six_month, last_year
FROM  (
   SELECT k.name, pr.keyword_id, pr.project_id, pr.created_at::date AS created_day
        , array_agg(DISTINCT pr.position) AS positions
   FROM   project_reports  pr
   JOIN   keywords         k  ON k.id = pr.keyword_id
   GROUP  BY k.id, pr.project_id, created_day -- k.id being the pk
   ) sub
LEFT JOIN crosstab(
    $$SELECT ARRAY[keyword_id, project_id], created_at::date, array_agg(DISTINCT position)
      FROM   project_reports
      WHERE  created_at::date IN (
                    current_date - 1
                  , current_date - 7
                  , (now() - interval '1 mon')::date
                  , (now() - interval '3 mon')::date
                  , (now() - interval '6 mon')::date
                  , (now() - interval '12 mon')::date
                  )
      GROUP  BY 1,2
      ORDER  BY 1,2$$
   ,$$VALUES 
       (current_date - 1)
      ,(current_date - 7)
      ,((now() - interval '1 mon')::date)
      ,((now() - interval '3 mon')::date)
      ,((now() - interval '6 mon')::date)
      ,((now() - interval '12 mon')::date)$$
   ) AS t (
        kp int[]
      , yesterday   int[]
      , last_week   int[]
      , last_month  int[]
      , three_month int[]
      , six_month   int[]
      , last_year   int[]
      ) ON t.kp[1] = keyword_id
       AND t.kp[2] = project_id;
```

To break it down, a simple **demo** of what I am doing in the crosstab:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
 $$SELECT *
   FROM  (
      VALUES
        ('{1,2}'::int[], current_date - 1, '{1,2}'::int[])
      , ('{1,3}'::int[], current_date - 1, '{1,2}'::int[])
      , ('{1,2}', current_date - 7, '{5,6,7}'::int[])
      , ('{1,3}', current_date - 7, '{5,6,7}'::int[])
      , ('{1,2}', (now() - interval '1 mon')::date, '{9,10}'::int[])
       -- 3 mon missing
      , ('{1,2}', (now() - interval '6 mon')::date, '{6,6,6}'::int[])
       -- 12 mon missing
      ) sub
    ORDER BY 1,2$$
   
,$$VALUES 
    (current_date - 1)
   ,(current_date - 7)
   ,((now() - interval '1 mon')::date)
   ,((now() - interval '3 mon')::date)
   ,((now() - interval '6 mon')::date)
   ,((now() - interval '12 mon')::date)$$
) AS t (
     kp int[]
   , yesterday   int[]
   , last_week   int[]
   , last_month  int[]
   , three_month int[]
   , six_month   int[]
   , last_year   int[]
   );
```

Result:

```
  kp   | yesterday | last_week | last_month | three_month | six_month | last_year
-------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+-----------
 {1,2} | {1,2}     | {5,6,7}   | {9,10}     |             | {6,6,6}   |
 {1,3} | {1,2}     | {5,6,7}   |            |             |           |
```

The rest should be obvious.

#### Comments

- I de-coupled the two parts and fused the plethora of correlated subqueries into a ***single*** subquery, which should be *much* faster. Then I use cross tabulation pull individual columns from this query. The syntax for `crosstab()` is the tricky part.
- I am not joining to `project_keywords`, it seems to be just noise. I am suspecting problems in your relational model.
- I seems you should include the `project_id` in the result to make sense. Else you should not GROUP BY it ...
- You can just subtract `integer` from `date`.